# How Do You Call a Controller Action That Will Return to The Calling Controller But Also Can Have A RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a controller in my .Net Core 3.1 app that calls another controller action. Before I added a `RedirectToAction` in the called controller everything worked fine. I now want that controller to redirect to an error page if appropriate, otherwise back to where it was called in the original controller.

Here is the code in my controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(IFormCollection collection, string saveClose)
{
    //do stuff
    LoadArrayDataForDB(Id, collection["names"].ToString(), collection["places"].ToString(), collection["countries"].ToString());
    //do more stuff
    
    return View(IVM);
}

//This was the Original LoadArrayDataForDB action
public void LoadArrayDataForDB(string id, string names, string places, string countries)
{
    //add error checking
    _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedNames(id);
    _adoSqlService.DeleteSelectedPlaces(id);
    _adoSqlService.DeleteCountries(id);
}

//This is how I need to change the LoadArrayDataForDB action
public void LoadArrayDataForDB(string id, string names, string places, string countries)
{ 
    //add error checking
    string done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedNames(id);
    if (done != "Successful")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errordescription = "Unable to delete names" });
    }

    done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedPlaces(id);
    if (done != "Successful")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errordescription = "Unable to delete places" });
    }       

    done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedCountries(id);
    if (done != "Successful")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errordescription = "Unable to delete countries" });
    }       
    //etc....
    //Just return back to next step in the Edit action
}
```

How can I do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your load function to this

```
[NonAction]
private string LoadArrayDataForDB( id, string names, string places, string countries)
{ 

    //add error checking

    string done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedNames(id,names); // I guess you 
                                                  // have to use names too
    if (done != "Successful")   return  "Unable to delete names";
   
    done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedPlaces(id,places);
    if (done != "Successful")return  "Unable to delete places";
    
    done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedCountries(id,contries);
    if (done != "Successful") return  "Unable to delete countries";
    
    //etc....
return string.Empty
)


or if you want to try all of them before return you can use this

var errMsg=string.Empty;

 string done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedNames(id,names); // I guess you 
                                                  // have to use names too
    if (done != "Successful")   errMsg=  "Unable to delete names";
   
    done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedPlaces(id,places);
    if (done != "Successful") errMsg+=  " Unable to delete places";
    
    done = _adoSqlService.DeleteAffectedCountries(id,contries);
    if (done != "Successful") errMsg+=  "Unable to delete countries";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg) return errMsg;

   //etc....
return string.Empty
```

Change your action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(IFormCollection collection, string saveClose)
{
    //do stuff

var errorDescription=  LoadArrayDataForDB(intid, collection["names"].ToString(), collection["places"].ToString(), collection["countries"].ToString())) 

if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorDescription) )
 return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorDescription });

    //do more stuff
    
    return View(IVM);
}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my description so I modified the post. I perform multiple DB actions in the load function. I need to be able to redirect if any of them fail with the error of what failed.

Comment: Thanks. I took what you had and made some minor changes (what you had would have worked as is). Since I was looking at the response for "done", that is what I assigned the error text too instead of errorDescription. Instead of returning string.Empty; I return "Successful". Then I just see if the value of done = "Successful". If not it will pass the value of "done". This way I can keep the rest of my code consistent.